# Angular4 ngIf is not updating

Tags: angular, asynchronous, angular-ng-if

The template is not detecting changes to the stock model when checkbox variable is set to true.  I've tried use change detection but not sure if I was implementing correctly, so I've removed from my code example for now. Oddly enough, I wasn't having an issue before I started pulling data from a remote service.

Here is my plunker example:
http://plnkr.co/edit/0EfkaSpk3Ag9p5NH5jJ2?p=preview

Here is my control:

```
    <tr *ngFor="let stock of stocksObservable | async;">
      <td>
        <input [checked]="stock.isChecked" (change)="stock.isChecked = !stock.isChecked;onSelectStock($event);" type="checkbox"> <a href="">{{ stock.number }}</a>  {{stock.isChecked}} 
      </td>
    </tr>
```

Within my ng-container, I should see stocks that I have selected. Instead, I see no changes or updates...

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Is Checked</th>
  </tr>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let stock of stocksObservable | async;">  
    <tr *ngIf="stock.isChecked">
      <td>
        <a href="">{{stock.number}}</a> {{stock.isChecked}} 
      </td>
    </tr>
  </ng-container>
</table>
```

Here's my class:

```
//services
branchesObservable : Observable<object> ; 
stocksObservable : Observable<object> ; 

isChecked: boolean;
selectable: boolean;

constructor( private stocksService: StocksService ) { 
  this.branchesObservable = this.stocksService.get_branches();
}

//fetch stock data into table
getBranchStocks(value){
  this.stocksObservable = this.stocksService.get_stocks(value);

}

//select stocks
onSelectStock(event) {
  this.isChecked = !this.isChecked;
}
```

Comment: You have `stocksObservable | async` twice. So you subscribe twice to the observable, send 2 http requests, and obtain two different arrays of stocks. Don't use async unless you really understand how it works.

Comment: I'm fairly new to angular and this is my first time dealing with observables so I'm still wrapping my head around it. I'm simply trying to loop through which stocks have been selected. Thanks for your help

Comment: track the checked in an array for each obj by keeping track of the index  instead and add/remove item to an array list of checked obj and traverse it normally. Got it working on your example .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using the observables in a wrong way. Observables are used to emit objects. So, when your object inside the observable is updated when checkbox is clicked its not the same object which is used in the next ngFor and hence not reflected as its subscription model, kind of two subscriptions.

I created a local variable stocks which is updated or assigned to via subscribe method.

I have modified plnkr code: http://plnkr.co/edit/7WBNDX53pCbf44QnlRo4?p=preview.

```js
    // import { Component, ChangeDetectionStrategy, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
    import { Component, ChangeDetectionStrategy, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
    import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

    import { StocksService } from './stocks.service';
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';



    @Component({
      selector: 'app-root',
      template: `
        <div class="wrapper">
          <select #branch (change)="getBranchStocks(branch.value)">
            <option value="null">select a branch</option>
            <option *ngFor="let branch of branchesObservable | async" value="{{ branch.branchId }}">{{ branch.name }}</option>
          </select>
          <table style="width:100%;">
            <tr>
              <th>Stock</th>
            </tr>
            <tr *ngFor="let stock of stocks">
              <td>
                <input [checked]="stock.isChecked" (change)="stock.isChecked = !stock.isChecked;onSelectStock($event);" type="checkbox"> <a href="">{{ stock.number }}</a>  {{stock.isChecked}} 
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          <table style="width:49%;float:left;border:0;">
            <tr>
              <th>Is Checked</th>
            </tr>
            <ng-container *ngFor="let stock of stocks">
              <tr *ngIf="stock.isChecked">
                <td>
                  <a href="">{{stock.number}}</a> {{stock.isChecked}} 
                </td>
              </tr>
            </ng-container>
          </table>
        </div>
      `,
    })

    export class AppComponent  {

        //services
        branchesObservable : Observable<object> ; 
        stocksObservable : Observable<object> ; 
        stocks:object;

        isChecked: boolean;
        selectable: boolean;

        constructor( private stocksService: StocksService ) { 
          this.branchesObservable = this.stocksService.get_branches();
        }

        //fetch stock data into table
        getBranchStocks(value){
          this.stocksObservable = this.stocksService.get_stocks(value);
          this.stocksObservable.subscribe(data=>this.stocks=data);
        }

        //select stocks
        onSelectStock(event) {
          this.isChecked = !this.isChecked;
        }


    }
```

I guess you are dealing with stocks which needs local updates as well as continuous updates from subscription as well. So, the ideal way would be to use BehaviorSubject in RxJS. A nice example of it can be found on https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-observable-data-services

Comment: I'll take a look at BehaviorSubject. But for sure this gets me where I need to be for now - thanks for your help

Comment: This helped me remove all the unnecessary junk from a component a colleague wrote, I thought I was going mad, but it was just terrible code, your reminder of how `checked` works helped me debug and fix by setting `[(ngModel)]="checkboxState"` (a boolean) on the ckeckbox, then using that in the ngIf on the ng-container. So simple, once you delete all the excessive functions and vars :D